# Hyperledger fabric authentication

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I am developing a blockchain network using Hyperledger Fabric (1.4) and I wanted to know if there's any User authentication mechanism for Fabric. For composer-rest-server there's passport but for fabric, I can't seem to find one.

Comment: Check this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43527599/how-are-new-participants-authenticated-into-a-channel-in-hyperledger-fabric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main authentication mechanism in Hyperledger Fabric are Membership Service Providers (MSP). You set these up in parallel to the blockchain and can connect them to LDAP, for example.

For authentication a MSP issues a certificate for a user's public key, which can then be used to authenticate.

More info on MSPs in the Hyperledger Docs: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/msp.html